# Invoking another application using URL Scheme in iphone

Tags: iphone, plist

i want to load another iphone application when i click the button on the current application. The application which has to be loaded is **DataStore** (appl name). I added URL scheme to this application in plist file. URL scheme is **dbapp**, URL identifier is **com.dbapp**.
In the current application(**Testdb**) i have the code is

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dbapp://"]];
}
```

But it is not invoking the **DataStore** application when i click the button. please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to embed a link into a hmtl document and have the embedded Safari load that html - e.g. via an external server or maybe.
When you click on the link you should see the registered application load. If it doesn't then you have to look for the error in registration of the url-handler.